# update draft state in promise using immer

Tags: reactjs, promise, immer.js

How to update draft in promise using immer? This is my example code, but it does not work, I get `TypeError: Cannot perform 'set' on a proxy that has been revoked`. Why this does not work?

```
produce(state, draft => {
  switch (event.key) {
    case 'v': {
      if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) {
        navigator.clipboard.readText().then(clipText => {
          draft.command = clipText;
          draft.position = clipText.length;
        }).catch(e => console.log(e));
      }
    break;
  }
}})
```

Comment: https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/async

Comment: async-await is not exactly what I was looking for, this is a switch with multiple cases and I don't want to make whole function async

Comment: The problem is you cannot put a promise into the draft function because it will not wait for the promise to resolve. You do not have to make the whole function async, just the draft callback :  async draft => {...(await)}}